# Finding the number of elements in a matrix

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newcomer, so cut me a bit of slack  :P

I need to write a Haskell function that goes through a matrix and outputs a list of all matching elements to a given element (like using filter) and then matches the list against another to check if they are the same.

```
checkMatrix :: Matrix a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
```

I have tried variations of using filter, and using the !! operator and I can't figure it out. I don't really want to get the answer handed to me, just need some pointers for getting me on the right path

```
checkMatrix :: Matrix a -> a -> [a] -> Bool 
checkMatrix matr a lst = case matr of
    x:xs | [] -> (i don't really know what to put for the base case)
         | filter (== True) (x:xs !! 0) -> checkMatrix xs a lst
```

Thats all i got, I'm really very lost as to what to do next

Comment: Welcome to SO. Well then, if you don't want others to think you want the answer handed to you, please show the attempts you have already made.

Comment: "I have tried .." - it is entirely appropriate and encouraged to include in your answer the literal code you have tried to compile and run (this includes multiple pieces of code), as well as the error which that code gave you.

Comment: What is `Matrix`?

Comment: `(== True)` is `id`.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** You want something to the effect of `filter someCondition (toList matrix) == otherList`, with minor details varying depending on your matrix type and your specific needs.

## The Full Answer

I don't know what `Matrix` type you're using, but the approach is going to be similar for any reasonably defined matrix type.

For this answer, I'll assume you're using the [`Data.Matrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) class from the package on Hackage called `matrix`.

You are right to think you should use `filter`. Thinking functionally, you want to eliminate some elements from the matrix and keep others, based on a condition. However, a matrix does not provide a natural way to perform `filter` on it, as the idea is not really well-defined. So, instead, we want to extract the elements from our matrix into a list first. The `matrix` package provides the following function, which does just that.

```
toList :: Matrix a -> [a]
```

Once you have a list representation, you can very easily use `filter` to get the elements that you want.

A few caveats and notes.

- If the matrix package that you're using doesn't define `toList` itself, check if it defines a `Foldable` instance for the matrix type. If it does, then `Data.Foldable` has a general-purpose `toList` that works for all `Foldable` types.
- Be careful with the ordering here. It's not entirely clear what *order* the elements should be put into the list in, since matrices are two-dimensional and lists are inherently one-dimensional. If the ordering matters for whatever you're doing, you might have to put some additional effort into guaranteeing the desired order. If it does not matter, consider using `Data.Set` or some other unordered collection instead of lists.
- I don't see any constraints in your `checkMatrix` implementation. Remember that comparing elements of lists adds an `Eq a` constraint, and if you want to use an unordered collection then that's going to add `Ord a` instead.